Ingest recursive JSON data which has a document per line into Databricks OR Azure Data Factory
I have multiple JSON files in the file structure:

Commodity1

Interval

YYYY

MM

DD

file1.json








Interval

YYYY

MM

DD

file2.json


DD

file3.json




MM

DD

file4.json


DD

file5.json











And so on.
All the JSON files have the same schema.
However, I'm having issues ingesting this data into Databricks. I've set the recursiveFileLookup option to true and I'm able to ingest it but I end up with a document per line (each file on one row).
Is there any way to merge the data into one row in Databricks?
Also, if anyone has a solution to ingest this data into a data flow in Azure Data Factory, please share!
Thanks!

you can use the collect_list function to aggregate the fields from all JSON files into lists.

Please read [ask], and then edit your question to provide a [mcve] with all relevant details. Right now, you only provided a high level requirement.

I have tried the below approach in the Azure databricks:
Read the filepath using recursiveFileLookup and merge the data into a single row.
df_files = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").json("/FileStore/tables/Commodity1/Interval/")
df_files.show(truncate=False)

+----------+----------+-----+
|commodity |interval  |value|
+----------+----------+-----+
|Commodity1|2024-01-01|100  |
|Commodity1|2024-01-01|200  |
|Commodity1|2024-01-01|300  |
|Commodity1|2024-01-02|150  |
|Commodity1|2024-01-02|250  |
+----------+----------+-----+

merged_df = df_files.agg(collect_list("value").alias("merged_values"))
merged_df.show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------+
|merged_values            |
+-------------------------+
|[100, 200, 300, 150, 250]|
+-------------------------+

grouped_df = df_files.groupBy("interval").agg(collect_list("value").alias("merged_values"))
grouped_df.show(truncate=False)

Results:
+----------+---------------+
|interval  |merged_values  |
+----------+---------------+
|2024-01-01|[100, 200, 300]|
|2024-01-02|[150, 250]     |
+----------+---------------+

In the above code reading all JSON files in the nested directory structure
Aggregating all values into a single list within one row & groupping by interval and collect values for each date

As I've stated before: Stack Overflow is not the place for custom solutions. The OP has not shown any work; as written, the question is off-topic until they edit to provide details.
